# Amber Smalltalk Collaboration and Version Control

Tags: amber-smalltalk

**How does version control and collaboration work with Amber?**

When I created a new package I saw that three files were created:

- js/MyPackage.deploy.js
- js/MyPackage.js
- st/MyPackage.st

Do I need to put all of them under version control?
Can I merge changes into only the .st file and have the Amber server pick them up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a short explanation of the three files:

- `st/MyPackage.st`: the Smalltalk source also known as fileout
- `js/MyPackage.js`: the equivalent to the Smalltalk source compiled to JS (including metadata such as Smalltalk sourcecode)
- `js/MyPackage.deploy.js`: equals the other `.js` file but does not contain metadata not needed in deployment

To run an Amber application one of the `.js` files is needed.
Which one depends on the deploy mode but for development the one without `.deploy` in the name is used.

The `.js` files in turn can be generated from the `.st` files using the Amber commandline compiler (e.g. through Grunt.js) or by doing a file-in in the IDE and commiting the relevant package.

In general, we keep all three files under version control but for now the most crucial ones are the `.st` files since those are usually easier to merge than generated JS code.

However, keeping and merging only the `.st` files is not sufficient since those are not loadable by Amber.
Nico for example uses a local git hook to recompile the `.st` files upon pulling the latest changes.
See [this message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/amber-lang/WPmmSJIUhSc/vWuZGIi6zB8J) from the Amber mailinglist.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. What do you mean .st files are not loadable by amber? I mean they are loadable as long as you are in "dev  mode" (deploy: false), right?


I just started implementing stuff to ease collaboration. [1] On my master amber will automatically compile extra .st files to Javascript if no Javascript files could be found.


The next step is to do this whenever the .st files changed (e.g. through a merge).


[1] https://github.com/machisuji/amber/commit/76e985980ded69252837d1bbe456be3bb6041760

Comment: The Amber startup process for now only loads `.js` files and extracts the Smalltalk sourcecode from the provided metadata. The `.st` files are provided for convenience.

Comment: By the way, your project looks interesting. Maybe you can announce it on our mailinglist and we can continue the discussion there. I guess we could use something like that :-)

Comment: Thanks, will do some time this weekend!